# Symfony 2 validation with related entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have User and Order entity. When user creates order I should check that user cash is greater then cost of order. How to do this?
Example Order entity:

```
class Order
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $user
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\App\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="orders")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\Min(limit = "1", message = "You must enter positive number")
     */
    private $price;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution - write own validation constraint. As example Unique constraint in FOS User bundle.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html).

> The purpose of the Callback assertion is to let you create completely
>   custom validation rules and to assign any validation errors to
>   specific fields on your object.

Comment: And how I should get user related to Order?

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna B how to validate user's entity field in order entity using Callback?